# How to check if a custom component is filled from the form of a parent component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with a form where there are some custom components. For example one of the custom components has an input text and a select (there can be as many ocurrences/repetitions of that pair as the user adds). In my custom component I check that is filled if all the pairs are filled. I would like to check in the parent component after submitting the form if the custom components are filled.

Parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: `
        ...
        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit(form)">
            <app-custom-component formControlName="customComponent1" [data]="dataCustomComponent1" [(ngModel)]="dataCustomComponent"></app-custom-component>
            ...
            <app-custom-component formControlName="customComponent2" [data]="dataCustomComponent2" [(ngModel)]="dataCustomComponent2"></app-custom-component>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        ...
    `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    dataCustomComponent1: PairTextSelect[];
    dataCustomComponent2: PairTextSelect[];

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ...
}
```

Custom component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-custom-component',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let row of data; let i=index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data[i].text" (keyup)="isFilled()" />
            <p-dropdown [options]="options" [(ngModel)]="data[i].option" (onChange)="isFilled()"></p-dropdown>
            <i *ngIf="i+1>1" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" (click)="removeOcurrence(i)"></i>
        </div>
        <div (click)="addOcurrence()">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Add ocurrence</span>
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})

export class CustomComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    isFilled: boolean;
    private _data: PairTextSelect[];

    @Input() set data(data: PairTextSelect[]) {
        this._data = data;
    }

    get data(): PairTextSelect[] {
        return this._data;
    }

    isFilled(): void {
        // Checks if the custom component is filled
    }

    ...
}
```

Model:

```
export class PairTextSelect {
    text: string;
    option: string;
}
```

So I guess I would need to check from the parent component the property "isFilled" of the custom component. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating a 'normal' array in your children, instead use a `FormArray`, since you are already using a Reactive Form. This way, also parent will be aware of whatever happens in the children. So I would do something like the following:

Parent:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    // we pass a formarray to the children
    formArr1: fb.array([]),
    formArr2: fb.array([])
  })
}
```

We need to pass the reference of the parent form to the child, as well as the name of the formarrays as string to be used in child. So your childtags would look like this:

```html
<app-custom-component [form]="form" [formArr]="form.controls.formArr1" 
   name="formArr1"></app-custom-component>

<app-custom-component [form]="form" [formArr]="form.controls.formArr2" 
   name="formArr2"></app-custom-component>
```

Child templates would look like this:

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div [formArrayName]="name">
    <div *ngFor="let a of formArr.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="text">
      <input formControlName="option">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the child TS, when we want to add a new object, we create a new formgroup:

```ts
@Input() formArr: FormArray;
@Input() form: FormGroup;
@Input() name: string;


addOccurance() {
  this.formArr.push(this.fb.group({
    text: ['', Validators.required],
    option: ['', Validators.required]
  }))
}
```

### **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rt1ngb?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Comment: I have tried this way but if I want to fill formArray1 and formArray2 from a service it doesn't work, I get the following error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. 
this.form = fb.group({
      formArr1: fb.array(this.arr1),
      formArr2: fb.array(this.arr2)
    })
I forked your example and edited it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3vu95?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You cannot assign data like that. You need to iterate the array and push formgroups to your formarray, sample here for your first array: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2s9ucf?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can access child component using `@ViewChild` decorator.

```
@ViewChild(CustomComponent) customComp: CustomComponent
```

Now you can access child component properties in parent component. This works only after child is loaded ie after `AfterViewInit` life cycle event.

```
customComp.PairTextSelect
```

will work now.